# How to List the tables names in the Sqlite3 database in Java

Tags: java, php, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 database in a java application. How to programmatically get names of all tables in the database? I have tried google and stackoverflow as well, and could NOT find a simple solution as yet. Here is the MySqli code I use with PHP, I am trying a similar approach in Java-Sqlite3

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $database . "");
while($cRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {

    $namm=$cRow[0];


    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $namm . "";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $namk = $rows[0];

    echo "<li type='square' style='margin-bottom:3px;'>" . $cRow[0] . " (" . $namk . ")</li>";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE ...`

Comment: Where what? that is the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You could use JDBC's built-in APIs for exploring the database metadata:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db")) {
    ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, null));
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this one and update.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();

SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper(this, "MYSQLITE.db", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
   String tableName = cursor.getString(0);
   if(tableName.equals("android_metadata")){     
     continue;
   }else{
      tableNames.add(tableName);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this snippet I already have and tried it 2 days back, it threw some error, I don't readily remember.  Will try to dig it up and give a try again.